# Accessing certain value from iframe and using it in parent page Javascript

Tags: javascript

Inside my iframe i have a dial that spits out angle when the needle moves. Instead of getting both dial and needle both inside frame, is it possible to show the angle value somewhere else in my parent page outside the iframe. This is the code i have.

```
function showIframeContent(id) {
  var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    try {
      var doc = (iframe.contentDocument)? window.frames[clkwise1].document.getElementId("demo").value;
      alert(doc.body.innerHTML);
    }
    catch(e) {
       alert(e.message);
    }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard and cross-browser way to access the content of an iframe is:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document
```

I would expect this to work in your case:

```
document.getElementById("clkwise1").contentWindow.document.getElementById("demo").value
```

(I'd need to see the page itself to confirm it - for example I assume "demo" is an input element. Also, note your typo in getElementById)

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWC6v/

Comment: That doesnt work Man.. This was the original code.  
    function showIframeContent(id) {
      var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
        try {
          var doc = (iframe.contentDocument)? iframe.contentdemo: iframe.contentdemo.document;
          alert(doc.body.innerHTML);
        }
        catch(e) {
           alert(e.message);
        }
      return false;
    }
 </script>'

Comment: I have slightly modified the code and added a live demo. I don't know what "contentdemo" means in your code, this is not a standard JavaScript property.